# How can I let metricbeat use iam policy to access other AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I am using metricbeat to monitor metrics from a few AWS accounts. I have read through the doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-aws.html

it says to configure the credential as environment variables or in aws credential file. But I'd like to use cross account IAM policy to access different AWS account. That means metricbeat needs to assume a role when it tries to query metrics. How can I achieve this in metrcibeat? I can't find related doc in their document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can specify the `IAM Role` like this

[Metricbeat Configuration Params](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-aws.html#_configuration_parameters)

```yaml
metricbeat.modules:
- module: aws
  period: 300s
  metricsets:
    - ec2
  role_arn: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-mb
```

I would say there is nothing like `Cross Account Policy`.

Your role has permissions based on the policies you assign to it via `IAM Policies`.

When you wanna use `Cross-Account IAM Roles`,  you still have to assign `IAM Policies` on the role you create in the destination account `+` an `IAM Trust Policy` as well so that you can assume the role from another account, In addition to that your source `IAM Role` must have permissions to assume the destination `IAM Role`

[IAM Role Delegation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html)

[How to use trust policies with IAM roles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/)

[IAM Tutorial: Delegate access across AWS accounts using IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)